# Recover a net device, I don't know IP-address, how to get arp?

Tags: arp

I have to recover a HP ILO3. It doesn't take a correct IP-address because it is misconfigured
and get 127.0.0.1
I have no serial cable to connect to serial port.
Other forums suggested that I change its arp to static like this

```
arp -s ip hwaddr
```

So I can telnet to it (I hope).

The question is: how to discover all arp address connected in a network?
I need a tool which gets mac-addresses  of machines connected directly to eth0 (direct connect without switch) or connected to a switch.
I have tried arp-scan but need an IP-address configured to get its address.

Comment: You should be able to configure the iLO from the BIOS setup screen. Is that an option?

Comment: No bios,is efi server

Comment: There's likely still some BIOS status and configuration screens. What is the model number of the HP server?

Comment: Rx 2620,no bios,only efi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found [here](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Integrity-Servers/Access-ILO-from-hpux/td-p/6805931),must give static adddress to hpilo via arp
First connect to your network hpilo with cable then
from linux

```
arp -s 192.178.0.22 MAC:ADDRESS:OF:HP:ILO
```

Of course use your subnet instead of 192.178.0.22,and then ping,if work
telnet to hpilo.